# React Router Error TypeError: _react.PropTypes is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to reactjs. I tried to add react router to my application and now get error:

> TypeError: _react.PropTypes is undefined
>   ./node_modules/react-router/lib/PropTypes.js
>   C:/react/myapplcation/node_modules/react-router/lib/PropTypes.js:8

I installed

```
npm install --save react-router
```

my `index.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
//import App from './Components/App';
import routes from './routes';

//ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

add a new `route.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, IndexRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from './Components/App';

export default(
<Route path="/" component={App} />
)
```

`package.json` file:

```
 {
   "name": "myapplication",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-select": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you probably intended to use [react-router-dom package](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start). If not, which version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: please share you package.json

Answer (score 2):

## Edit:

Just try to get the lastest version of `react-router`

Run `npm i react-router@latest`

---

I'm almost sure that you should be using `react-router-dom`, but if this isn't the case...

Run `npm i react-router-dom` and change

```
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
```

To

```
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
```

---

And if you are wondering why getting the error

> _react.PropTypes is undefined

This happens because on the later versions of `react`, `PropTypes` was a exported package but then they removed from `react` and created `prop-types`.

Probably you are with a newer version of react, but older version of `react-router`, wich uses `import {PropTypes} from 'react'` or `React.PropTypes`, but it doesn't exists in your newer version of react.

And looking ate your `package.json`, you are using `"react-router": "^2.8.1"` wich is a older version (now the estable is in 3.x), so probably this version uses old version of react.

As you can see in the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#removed-deprecations) of react 16.0.0.

> The deprecations introduced in 15.x have been removed from the core package. `React.createClass` is now available as create-react-class, `React.PropTypes` as prop-types, `React.DOM` as react-dom-factories, react-addons-test-utils as react-dom/test-utils, and shallow renderer as react-test-renderer/shallow. See 15.5.0 and 15.6.0 blog posts for instructions on migrating code and automated codemods.

Comment: added package.json above.

Comment: changed from 'react-router' to 'react-router-dom' and now the new error message : Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom'

Comment: Did you run `npm install --save react-router-dom` ?

Comment: @user788448 you could also upgrade the version of `react-router`

Comment: Just installed react-router-dom and error message:Attempted import error: 'browserHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'. How do I remove old version react-router and reinstall new version?

Comment: @user788448 run `npm i react-router@latest` to get the lastest version

Comment: installed latest version react-router and react-router-dom, error message: /src/index.js
Attempted import error: 'browserHistory' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'. package.json "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",

Comment: if you are going to import `browserHistory` it need to be from `react-router`, if you are going to use `react-router-dom` then you need to import other things, because of the new version, the names have changed

Comment: with `react-router-dom` is `import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';`

Answer (score 0):

I referenced to this tutorial https://codeburst.io/getting-started-with-react-router-5c978f70df91 and found the solution. Thanks everyone.